# salesforce formula field calculating one input value and one picklist

Tags: visualforce, formula

I have a scenario , volume (input field), trade (picklist-3 values), total volume

total volume should be calculated based on volume and trade selection , example: totalvolume= volume*2900  if picklist1 selected(trade), any idea?

Comment: Hi rajashekar, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to be more clear. What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

If the picklist values are hardcoded pieces of text, you can interpret them in your formula, using an IF or a CASE statement e.g.:

```
Volume__c * 
CASE(TEXT(Trade__c),
'picklist1',2900,
'picklist2',4000,
'picklist3',6000,
0
)
```

Comment: i got syntax error- missing '}'

Comment: sorry, missed a comma (behind Trade__c)  ). Now added.